# Make a Form from JavaScript Object Properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have a web app that runs off of JSON data, and I extract a portion and end up with an object that has some properties:

```
var formProps = {
    Name: "Some Name value",
    Age: "18", 
    AnotherField: "Some other value"
}
```

I'm trying to find an efficient way to create a form from the properties.

```
<div class="formitem">
<label>Some Name Value</label>
<input type="text" name="AnotherField" value="Some other value"/>
</div>
```

I can't decide if I should generate the HTML and dump it into another div that already exists on the page, or if I should create new DOM elements via JS...

Comment: Try both, see which works more "efficiently".

Comment: What kind of "efficiency" are you trying to reach? Fast loading? Easy maintaining? Fast code on your server? Fast form creation on the client ..? Unless you've tens of thousands of the elements in your form, I'd stick to the maintainablity. Also, the provided JSON is a bit confusing for the purpose. Your data structure should help you on what you're doing, like an array of element objects having all the needed properties for a control element instead of a hard reading list of properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be dynamic you have no choice but to create new DOM elements from JavaScript.

One way to do it is to define the form item structure with an HTML template, this will allow you to defined much of the structure in HTML. Then you can clone, customize and append this template in your page for every property you have in your object.

```js
const formProps = {
  Name: "Some Name value",
  Age: "18", 
  AnotherField: "Some other value"
}

function createField(prop, value) {
  const tpl = document.querySelector('#formitem-tpl');
  const clone = document.importNode(tpl.content, true);
  clone.querySelector('label').innerHTML = prop;
  const input = clone.querySelector('input');
  input.value = value;
  input.name = prop;
  return clone;
}

const form = document.querySelector('#form');

for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(formProps)) {
  form.appendChild(createField(key, val));
}
```

```html
<template id="formitem-tpl">
  <div class="formitem">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" name="" value=""/>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="form">
</div>
```